# vuepress dev not rendering locally

Tags: vuepress

I have this Vuepress project https://github.com/hanxue/wujiquan-vuepress that is published on [enter link description here](https://wujiquan.net) . The directory structure and `config.js` works well.

But on my local machine, when I run `yarn run build`, equivalent of `vuepress dev docs`, the pages do not render correctly.

Generating the static site works though

```
yarn run build
python -m http.server -d docs\.vuepress\dist 8080
```

#### Environment

```
"vuepress": "^1.0.0-alpha.24"
node: v10.16.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to https://github.com/vuejs/vuepress/issues/1935?

> The paths to the CSS and JS files in index.html are absolute (starts
>   with /), so viewing index.html using the file protocol doesn't work
>   (you need to host it on a server so the HTTP protocol are used).